# Browser dependency problem in image display

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, image

In my page, I am displaying a report after the user selects some information. On a button `onclick` event, I am displaying an image which rotates itself to indicate to the user that the request is being processed. The image rotates in the Firefox but not in IE(it just displays the image).  Please give me your suggestions.

with regards

R.Prakash

Comment: Is this an animated GIF that IE is not animating?

Comment: please provide some more information, source code, etc.

Comment: Need more information.  What do you mean by it "rotates itself"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is because your page has submitted a standard, synchronous request to the server and is waiting for the response.  I've noticed that in certain versions of IE even an animated GIF will freeze up.

You may want to change your server request to be asynchronous (a la AJAX).  And one of the benefits will be no freezing of animated images.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of image are you using? GIF or PNG?

Animated PNGs (APNG) don't work in Internet Explorer.

But APNG is a format not so popular.
If you are using an animated gif, check the settings of your IE:
**Internet Options > Advanced > Multimedia > Play animations in webpages** must be enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening that page on other machine.